# How to pass an Input inside a max() function in R studio (shiny App)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to pass the input `input$sel`  into the max() function
`max(dataf$get(input$sel))`
Known that `dataf` is data frame that has values.

My goal is that I get the max value from a column from `dataf` through the select input `input$sel`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Summarize Data and then Plot 
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$sel)
    df <- dataf %>%  
      group_by(code) %>% 
      summarise(output = get(input$sel))
    print(df)
  })
  
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({  
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes(y = output, x = code) ) 
    g + geom_bar( stat = "sum")
    
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = "sel",
              label = "eine möglichkeit auswählen",
             
               list("vaccinationsTotal","peopleFirstTotal","peopleFullTotal","peopleBoosterTotal")),
 
   plotOutput("plot")

######   here is my approuch   ##########

max(dataf$get(input$sel))


)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input values are only available inside the app server. More properly, they need reactive contexts provided by observe/reactive.

Try this instead:

Note: I used `iris` dataset as dummy data to make the code reproducible.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sel",
    label = "eine möglichkeit auswählen",
    choices = names(iris)
  ),
  # list("vaccinationsTotal","peopleFirstTotal","peopleFullTotal","peopleBoosterTotal")),

  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Summarize Data and then Plot
    data <- reactive({
        req(input$sel)
        df <- iris %>%
            group_by(Species) %>%
            summarise(output = max(get(input$sel)))
        print(df)
        df
    })
    
    
    
    # Plot
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        g <- ggplot(data(), aes(y = output, x = Species))
        g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.
Now I am trying to use textOutput( ), and I wonder how should it be used in this specific case.

Comment: @lawkira you can check `textOutput` [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/textOutput.html) and if you still need help you can ask another question, i'll be glad to  answer.